# Jquery Menu mouse over not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, menu, onmouseover, onmouseout

Hi am trying to implement a simple menu using jquery but with no luck.
Kindly look into this fiddle.Thanks in advance
http://jsfiddle.net/Gg3cR/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of visibility: hidden; you need display: none; to start out with

here is updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gg3cR/13/

EDIT:
It will probably be better in the long run to keep the list in a div, and show/hide the div on mouse over

Here is a link to show the difference between the two:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

if you want to use visibility still, you could use .css('visibility', visibilityState)

Comment: Thanks a lot..But why should it be display:none and not visibility:hidden?

Comment: "The matched elements will be hidden immediately, with no animation. This is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'none')" - from http://api.jquery.com/hide/ - basically since hide and show use the display property, you need to also